# Создать json и отправить методом POST

Tags: javascript, json

При клике на товар, мне нужно сохранить 2 вещи, количество и id товара. Id товара, это : `$('#nameid').val()`, количество товара это `$('#qty').val()`. Например, я выбрал пластилин 2 шт, а потом фломастеров 5 штук, и мне надо id: 1, qty: 2; id:2, qty: 5. Как это реализовать?

Comment: собирай объект из этого всего и юзай JSON.stringify() https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправить методом POST, в JSON – всё это за вас сделает jQuery своим методом [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), ведь jQuery вы уже пользуетесь, судя по примерам кода.

Судя по коду, опять же, у вас товары добавляются по одному. Выбрал один, нажал что-то типа «В корзину», затем туда же вписал второй, и опять нажал – всё должно сохраняться?

Вторая кнопка, «Отправить», должна все собранное отправлять на сервер методом POST?

Тогда добавление в корзину:

```
var basket = {};
$('#btn-add').on('click', function(){
    basket[$('#nameid').val()] = parseInt( $('#qty').val());
});
```

В итоге в объекте `basket` ключами будут `id` товара, а значениями выбранные количества – это удобно для последующего изменения количеств, редактирования корзины:

```
"66912": 2,
"33309": 1,
```

А отправка может быть примерно такой. Сначала из корзинки собрать массив объектов в формате, как вам требуется, а затем отправить эти данные на сервер:

```
$('#btn-send').on('click', function(){
    var data = [], id;
    for( id in basket) {
        data.push({
          id: id,
          qty: basket[id]
        });
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/order/add', // url куда отправлять
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(response){
            // выполнится после успешной отправки
        },
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: Эй, этот код же не JSON отправляет, а application/x-form-urlencoded...

Comment: да, поспешил.  Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, что вы уже сделали на данный момент, как у вас организована страница, какова в целом логика работы. 
В самом общем случае, если то, что вы указали верно для всех продуктов, то, например, обработчик клика может быть таким:

```
function clickHandler() {
    products.push({
        'id' : $('#nameid').val(),
        'qty' : $('#qty').val()
    });
}
```

Массив `products` при этом должен быть определен заранее.

Далее, если вам принципиален JSON строкой, то можно вызвать:

```
JSON.stringify(products)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
a = [{
  id: 1,
  qty: 2
}, {
  id: 2,
  qty: 4
}]
document.write(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let list  = null,
    add   = null,
    wrap  = null,
    empty = null,
    send  = null,
    
    // В input, где выбирается количество, ставим data-type с ID товара
    template = `<input type='number' pattern='[\d]*' value='1' data-type='%t' /> <span>%s</span>`;

function init(){
  let s = document.querySelector.bind(document);
  
  list  = s('#list');
  add   = s('#add');
  wrap  = s('#wrapper');
  empty = s('#empty');
  send  = s('#send');
  
  add.addEventListener('click', addHandler);
  send.addEventListener('click', sendHandler);
  
}
function declOfNum(n, t){n = Math.abs(n);return t[(n % 100 > 4 && n % 100 < 20)? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][(n % 10 < 5) ? n % 10: 5]];}

function addHandler(){
  let e = list[list.selectedIndex],
      d = document.createElement('div');
  
  d.className = 'row';
  
  d.innerHTML = template.replace('%t', e.value).replace('%s', e.dataset.f);
  d.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(ev){    
    d.querySelector('span').innerHTML = declOfNum(this.value, [e.dataset.f, e.dataset.s, e.dataset.t]);
  });
  
  if(wrapper.children.length >= 1 && wrapper.children[0].id === 'empty')
    empty.style.display = 'none';
  else
    empty.style.display = 'block';
  
  wrapper.appendChild(d);
}

function sendHandler(){
  let b = [], t = {};
  // Ищем input, откуда можем взять и количество, и ID;
  // сохраняем во временный объект ради сложения количества одинаковых товаров
  Array.from(wrapper.querySelectorAll('.row input')).forEach(e => e.dataset.type in t ? t[e.dataset.type] += +e.value : t[e.dataset.type] = +e.value);
  // Извлекаем товар и его количество в нужный формат: [{typeID: ..., count: ...}, ...]
  Object.keys(t).forEach(e => b.push({typeID: e, count: t[e]}));
  
  // Готовый объект в b, можно fetch юзать или что угодно
  console.info('Send', b);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

```css
select{
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  padding-right: 0;
}
select:focus, input:focus{outline: none;}
input[type=number]{
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,.1);
}
input[type=button]{
  height: 30px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  min-width: 30px;
}
hr{
  border: 0;
  background-color: #d6d9dc;
  color: #d6d9dc;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
#wrapper{
  padding-left: 5%;
}
#empty{
  color: #ccc;
}
.row:not(:last-child){
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<select id='list'>
  <option value='plasticine' data-f='пластелин' data-s='пластелина' data-t='пластелинов'>Пластелин</option>
  <option value='feltPen' data-f='фломастер' data-s='фломастера' data-t='фломастеров'>Фломастер</option>
  <option value='pancil' data-f='карандаш' data-s='карандаша' data-t='карандашей'>Карандаш</option>
</select>
<input type='button' id='add' value='+' />
<hr />
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='empty'>Пусто</div>
</div>
<hr />
<input type='button' id='send' value='Отправить' />
```

P. S. Что-то расписал много, зато наглядно :)